# Safety of executing arbitrary regular expressions

Tags: regex, security

I really can't think of any, but could there be malicious effects of allowing users to run arbitrary regular expressions?

For example, say I have a website where people can try out regular expressions on a block of text -- is there anything I'd have to "sanitize" in the same way as for SQL statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some regular expressions can be computationally very complex and/or require a lot of memory and running many of them could degrade performance or lead to a denial of service.

Answer (score 1):

Perl regular expressions can execute arbitrary code snippets.  Even without that feature, a malicious regex could use up all the CPU/RAM on your server.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: Excellent link, but a link-only answer is not really great (bitrot is just one of the problems). Could you summarize the information quickly in your answer?